# Is Office Online Server Required for an SSRS Reports-Only Environment?

Tags: 2016, reporting-services, oos

I'm setting up a new SharePoint 2016 minrole Farm to house 2000+ SSRS reports. This is a 'stop-gap' solution as we search for a more permanent reporting solution in the next 3-4 years.

Do I need to install Office Online Server (OOS) given this Farm is to house (and provide dedicated user access to) SSRS reports only? Or would this be deemed unnecessary / surplus to requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS integrated mode does not use OOS. You do not need OOS in that environment. Keep in mind you'll need to set your Role to Custom for the servers hosting the SSRS Service Instance.